# Change all text fonts in Libreoffice Impress presentation?

Tags: presentations, libreoffice-impress

Anyone got any idea how to change the font of all text boxes in an Impress presentation? 
Applying a Master slide doesn't appear to have any useful effect.

Answer (score 16):

Press F11, you will see a style dialog. Right click on "Default", and change the font.

Comment: This method allows to change the font/size for all the text in the impress presentation wich uses the same style.

Comment: yes, this works automatically only for my Titles... no for Added text... ;/

Comment: The problem is that Impress distinguishes beteen Graphic Styles and Presentation Styles (the two icons at the top-left of the Styles and Formatting dialog). Although both lists have a style like "Title", they do not seem to be in any way related. I haven't found a way yet to change the font for all Presentation styles at once (they don't seem to be hierarchical like the Graphics Styles)

Answer (score 14):

Go into the outline. Select all the text that you want and change them it to a font of your choice. It should now be reflected in the presentation.

This is much easier than selecting one slide at a time to change the font.

Comment: Ahh yes good point, `view` > `outline` > ctrl + A. Nice!

Comment: The text in text boxes doesn't seem to appear in the overview. Any way to apply this to all text boxes too?

Answer (score 4):

first, you can use font substitution in LibreOffice settings, however, this will have only effect on your computer. I also faced this problem and as I remember, I did some experiments with the XML files inside the  OpenDocument file. I extracted it using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and then used [PSPad editor](http://www.pspad.com/en/) to search and replace the font names in the files. It is a longer time ago so I do not remember the exact procedure. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Select all (Ctrl + A)
Go up to Format
Select on Character

Then make the changes you want and it will be applied to all text that is selected.

You can do the same if you only wanted to change some of the text boxes on the slide by only selecting the text boxes you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  on macOS (style dialog)
2. select any text
   styles dialog highlights the style you are using
3. In styles dialog click the bucket (Fill Format mode icon)
4. Use right mouse button on the highlighted style and choose modify.

   A window menu opens
5. Select font effects, in the color section select color and...
6. Tick scheme option (above shadow option)